# How to add class or id to java script

Tags: javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle (t) {
    if (t.childNodes[0].innerHTML == "+ Šta je to web stranica?") {
        t.childNodes[0].innerHTML = "- Šta je to web stranica?";
    } else {
        t.childNodes[0].innerHTML = "+ Šta je to web stranica?";
    }
    }
    </script>
```

How to add class or id to this code like it is added inside this code :

```
<script>
$("div.toggle").click(function () {
$("p#toggle-1").toggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(selector).attr('id', id)` to add an ID, and `$(selector).addClass(class)` to add a class.

Comment: I am really noob in java script , so can you please add class or id name like u want into this code :